# Please give an example of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is inner product space and $f$ is a transformation $f:V\to V$.

Please give an example of a transformation $f$ that follows: 
$$(x,x)=(f(x),f(x))$$ 
while $f$ isn't linear transformation.

Comment: I'm assuming this is talking about the transformation of a point $(x,x)$on a cartesian plane. This only works if $f(x)=x$, but since it can't be linear, it cannot exist. It will work for any $f(x)$ that crosses $f(x)=x$ at the point of intersection, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you asking for an example of $f$ such that $T(x,x)=(f(x),f(x))$ is a linear transformation but $f$ is not a linear transformation?

Answer (score 2):

Your question was a bit hard to follow so I have two answers depending on how I interpret the question.

First interpretation of your question: Is there a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x,x)=(f(x),f(x))$, but $f$ is not linear?

Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x,x)=(f(x),f(x))$ is linear.

This requires: $T(\alpha u) = T(\alpha x, \alpha x) = (f(\alpha x), f(\alpha x)) = \alpha(f(x), f(x)) = \alpha T(u)$.

And, $T(u+v) = T((x,x)+(y,y)) = T(x+y,x+y) = (f(x+y),f(x+y)) = (f(x)+f(y), f(x) + f(y)) = (f(x),f(x))+(f(y),f(y)) = T(x, x) + T(y, y) = T(u)+T(v)$.

This shows that $T$ can be linear only if $f$ is linear, no such examples exist.

Second interpretation of your question: Is there a function $f$ satisfying $(x,x) = (f(x),f(x))$ such that $f$ is not linear?

This is equivalent to asking "is there a function such that $f(x) = x$ which is not linear?" It's easy for you to verify that any such function is linear, so again there is no example of such an $f$.

**EDIT**

We now know $V$ is an inner product space, so I assume $(x,x)$ is an inner product. I will change the notation to $\langle x, x \rangle = \Vert x\Vert^2$. We want to find a nonlinear $f$ such that for every $x \in V$, $\Vert x \Vert^2 = \Vert f(x) \Vert ^2$. This is equivalent to a function $f$ such that $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert f(x) \Vert$, i.e. an isometric function.

Consider the example where $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, and Let $f$ be defined by $f(x,y) = (\Vert(x,y)\Vert, 0)$. This function clearly satisfies the property that $\Vert u \Vert = \Vert f(u) \Vert$, but it is not linear. I'm not currently awake enough to provide an example of a function that can be defined in terms of an arbitrary inner product space $V$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I forget to tell the $V$ is inner product space and $f$ is a transformation $f:V\to V$.